# Rails 3 route for subpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes

I have a little problem in rails 3 routing

I have a controller page which is showing my pages like

```
example.com/some_page_title
```

but now I need to put there a subpage in this current page

```
example.com/some_page_title/some_subpage_title
```

my route looks like this now:

```
match ':title' => 'page#show'
```

but what to do to show subpage? I recognize this is subpage by fild parent_id is it true this has to be a subpage but is it false this is main page. Do I have to put my subpages to other controller or even in other table of database?

What to do if want to change my subpage to be a normal page, for now I just remove the parent_id and is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
match :parent_title/:title => "pages#show"
```

Assuming:

```
class Page
   has_many :subpages, :class_name => "Page"
end
```

in Controller

```
def show
  if params[:parent_title].present?
    parent = Page.find_by_title params[:parent_title]
    @page = parent.subpages.find_by_title params[:title] if parent.present?
  end
end
```

Comment: almost working :) but have problem to getting data from table

Comment: PG::Error: ERROR:  column pages.page_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages"  WHERE "pages"."page_id" = 6 ...
                                              ^
: SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages"  WHERE "pages"."page_id" = 6 AND "pages"."title" = 'Info' LIMIT 1